# Get div content value during print post data?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and php and I want to get div content data when I `print_r($_POST)`

I used `add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_save_meta_fields' );` wordpress hook to save data or update data.

When I do `print_r($_POST)` I get all things except **selected_element_all** div content.

How could I get data or resolve this ?

jquery code ( for get data from another file)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var postid = "<?php echo $post_id;?>";
  jQuery("#sel_all_mmy").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      data: {
        'post_id': postid
      },
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/get_all_make_model.php?",
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery(".selected_element_all").append(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML Div where i append data

```
<div  class="selected_element_all" style="font-size:15px">  </div>
```

And finally PHP code i used

```
<?php 

    function wpse_save_meta_fields( $post_id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        exit();
    }

    add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_save_meta_fields' );
?>
```

Comment: $_POST will get the input type values. selected_element_all is the div

Comment: ok so when i used input type then after i do $_POST so i 'll get data  or not ?

Comment: ok let me try it.

Comment: i tried it by using a hidden input type and store value to hidden field but when i get by using print_r($_POST) nothing showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way

take a input hidden field in your div just like

```
<input type=hidden name="my_val" class="my_val" value="">   </div>
```

then use it in your jquery script like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var postid ="<?php echo $post_id;?>";
    jQuery("#sel_all_mmy").click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        data:{'post_id':postid},
        type:'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/get_all_make_model.php?",
        success: function(data){
             jQuery(".selected_element_all").data(data);
             jQuery(".my_val").val(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And print_r that value in your PHP function like 
`print_r($_POST['my_val'])`;

I hope it's working.